# how to make a horizontal scroll animation in flutter

Tags: listview, animation, flutter, scroll

I want to make a scroll-able list view with this animation like this in flutter how can I accomplish that[image]

PS: don't mind the buggy animation it's just for illustration only

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider 
You can define a class with `title` and `image url` see full code below
and set `CarouselSlider` `enlargeCenterPage: true`

code snippet

```
//Auto playing carousel
    final CarouselSlider autoPlayDemo = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 0.7,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      items: payloadList.map((payload) {
        return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(payload.title),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    payload.imageUrl,
                    height: 250,
                    width: 250,
                    //fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          );
        });
      }).toList(),
    );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Payload {
  String title;
  String imageUrl;

  Payload({this.title, this.imageUrl});
}

final List<Payload> payloadList = [
  Payload(
    title: "Title 1",
    imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/250x200',
  ),
  Payload(
    title: "Title 2",
    imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/250x200',
  ),
  Payload(
    title: "Title 3",
    imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/250x200',
  ),
];

final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];

void main() => runApp(CarouselDemo());

final Widget placeholder = Container(color: Colors.grey);

final List child = map<Widget>(
  imgList,
  (index, i) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                    Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                'No. $index image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
).toList();

List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
  List<T> result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

class CarouselWithIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarouselWithIndicatorState createState() => _CarouselWithIndicatorState();
}

class _CarouselWithIndicatorState extends State<CarouselWithIndicator> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: true,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: map<Widget>(
          imgList,
          (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class CarouselDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Manually operated Carousel
    final CarouselSlider manualCarouselDemo = CarouselSlider(
      items: child,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
    );

    //Auto playing carousel
    final CarouselSlider autoPlayDemo = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 0.7,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      items: payloadList.map((payload) {
        return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(payload.title),
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(
                    payload.imageUrl,
                    height: 250,
                    width: 250,
                    //fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          );
        });
      }).toList(),
    );

    //Button controlled carousel
    Widget buttonDemo() {
      final basicSlider = CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        viewportFraction: 0.9,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        initialPage: 2,
      );
      return Column(children: [
        basicSlider,
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
          Flexible(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => basicSlider.previousPage(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
              child: Text('←'),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () => basicSlider.nextPage(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
              child: Text('→'),
            ),
          ),
          ...Iterable<int>.generate(imgList.length).map(
            (int pageIndex) => Flexible(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => basicSlider.animateToPage(pageIndex,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.linear),
                child: Text("$pageIndex"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ]);
    }

    //Pages covers entire carousel
    final CarouselSlider coverScreenExample = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 1.0,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: false,
      items: map<Widget>(
        imgList,
        (index, i) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(i), fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    //User input pauses carousels automatic playback
    final CarouselSlider touchDetectionDemo = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 3),
      items: imgList.map(
        (url) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 1000.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );

    //Non-looping manual Carousel
    final CarouselSlider nonLoopingCarousel = CarouselSlider(
      items: child,
      scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
    );

    //Vertical carousel
    final CarouselSlider verticalScrollCarousel = CarouselSlider(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 3),
      items: imgList.map(
        (url) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 1000.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );

    //create full screen Carousel with context
    CarouselSlider getFullScreenCarousel(BuildContext mediaContext) {
      return CarouselSlider(
        autoPlay: true,
        viewportFraction: 1.0,
        aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(mediaContext).size.aspectRatio,
        items: imgList.map(
          (url) {
            return Container(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0.0)),
                child: Image.network(
                  url,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 1000.0,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      );
    }

    CarouselSlider getOnDemandCarousel(BuildContext mediaContext) {
      return CarouselSlider.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 15,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) => Container(
          child: Text(itemIndex.toString()),
        ),
      );
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Carousel slider demo')),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            /*Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Manuell Carousel'),
                  manualCarouselDemo,
                ])),*/
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  //Text('Auto Playing Carousel'),
                  autoPlayDemo,
                ])),
            /*Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Button Controlled Carousel'),
                  buttonDemo(),
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Full Screen Carousel'),
                  coverScreenExample,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Carousel With Indecator'),
                  CarouselWithIndicator(),
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Pause When Touched Carousel'),
                  touchDetectionDemo,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('No infinity scroll carousel'),
                  nonLoopingCarousel,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Vertical scroll carousel'),
                  verticalScrollCarousel,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                //Builder needed to provide mediaQuery context from material app
                child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                  return Column(children: [
                    Text('Full screen carousel'),
                    getFullScreenCarousel(context),
                  ]);
                })),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                  return Column(children: [
                    Text('On demand item carousel'),
                    getOnDemandCarousel(context),
                  ]);
                })),*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```